# LINQ Include with Inner Join isn´t Working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, blazor

I´ve been trying to run the query

```
dbContext.Model.Include(x => x.ListItems);
```

But I always get a Left Join and i need a Inner Join. I tried adding this to my context class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<LogTL>()
                        .HasOne(p => p.ListaFluxos)
                        .WithMany()
                        .IsRequired(); ;
        }
```

but still no success.

Comment: `Include` is not about JOIN but about loading related entities. In this case, you are trying to load collection, which is Eager Loading and which has no direct translation to the SQL So EF team decided to add LEfT join to related table and remove duplicates on the client side.

Comment: Since this is normal EF behavior that can't be changed  there's nothing to do here.

Comment: I´ve read [here](https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/46563362/include---is-not-working-as-left-join--entity-framework-6-) that EF would generate a Left Join for optional relationships and Inner for Required, I even tried to change my models but I always get Left Join. I should use a Inner Join because I need to return the data only when its tied to its items.

Comment: That's about including references, not collections. Collections are never required. There's no way to require that a collection contain items. They can always be empty and therefore a left join is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need an Inner Join? EF by default will use a Left Join to accommodate Models that may not have ListItems.

If you want only Models that have ListItems then you can query that with:

```
dbContext.Model.Include(x => x.ListItems).Where(x => x.ListItems.Any()).ToList();
```

Though that may not result in EF producing an Inner Join. In the end I guess what matters is why you feel you need an Inner Join vs. a Left Join. If it is a concern around performance, that is generally better met by addressing indexing and leveraging things like projection to optimize the queries run. If instead there is a very specific (and typically more complex) query you want to reproduce via EF, a better approach can be to leverage something like a View in the database and map an entity model(s) to the result.

Comment: I´ve read [here](https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/46563362/include---is-not-working-as-left-join--entity-framework-6-) that EF would generate a Left Join for optional relationships and Inner for Required, I even tried to change my models but I always get Left Join. I should use a Inner Join because I need to return the data only when its tied to its items. But I wonder how am I supposed to set my models foi it to identify those are Required and then build the query using Inner on the .Include().

Comment: It would most likely depend on the relationship. In the case of a one-to-many relationship (Parent & Children) then it would use a Left Join since while the rule might be that a Child requires a parent, there can be parents that have no children. An inner join would exclude those Parents. In the case of a Many-to-One sided-relationship such as loading a Child with it's associated Parent, it could use an Inner Join where that relationship is required. That's not to say that it necessarily does though. In the end what EF generates isn't as important as whether it returns the data you expect.